# Небезопасный модуль образа SAFESEH. glut32.lib(glut32.dll) и что с ним делать?

Tags: glut, c++, visual-studio, opengl

Небольшая программка с использованием технологий OpenGL запускается лишь только при типе проекта `Debug`, но не `Release`.  Что делать Я не знаю и прошу объяснить как чайнику в чем может быть проблема и возможные способы её решения. Среда `Visual Studio Ultimate 2013`.
Я знаю, что вы опытные программисты и наверняка знаете в чем загвоздка. Спасибо!

Comment: о да, мы телепаты и можем подсматривать в чужие исходники на большом расстоянии. 

Там случайно  не c++/cli?

Comment: Всего 3 инклуда:
glut.h
cmath
complex
Да, C++

Comment: c++ и с++/cli это немного разные вещи.

Но может быть и для релиз версии неправильно настроны параметры компилятора.

Comment: Я дополнительные зависимости в компоновщике настраивал для всех конфигураций одни и те же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть предположение, что `VS2013` не нравится то, что библиотека была скомпилирована давно, когда не было проверки стека и SEH-фрейма от переполнения локальных (выделенных на стеке) буферов, с последующим затиранием адреса возврата и адреса обработчика исключений. Современные компиляторы вставляют код, проверяющий эти адреса. Ранее такое было не везде.

Возможно, стоит прицепить исходники глута к проекту или перебилдить саму либу.

[Сорцы](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut36.zip)

В архиве есть папка `lib/glut`. Стоит заглянуть туда.

Comment: Здравствуйте Антон! Благодарю за разумный ответ. Скорее всего вы правы и нужно заново собрать либу. Еще не зная предложенного вами решения, сменил среду и компилятор, главное – заработало. Студия очень тяжелая для моих любительских программ. Спасибо.