# Небезопасный модуль для образа SAFESEH.

Tags: visual-studio, c++, opengl

Небольшая программка с  OpenGL запускается лишь только при типе проекта Debug, но не Release.
Среда Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Я знаю, что вы опытные программисты и наверняка знаете в чем загвоздка. Спасибо!

```
glut32.lib(glut32.dll) : error LNK2026: небезопасный модуль для образа SAFESEH.
fatal error LNK1281: Не удается создать образ SAFESEH.
```

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244039/c-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-safeseh-glut32-lib-glut32-dll-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) и [здесь](http://www.wasm.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=46774)